# Expected norm of matrix product with random unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces, singular-values

Let $S_d = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \|x\| = 1\}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$. Note that
\begin{align}
    \max_{x \in S_d} \|A x\| &= \max \sigma(A) & \text{(spectral norm)} \\
    \min_{x \in S_d} \|A x\| &= \min \sigma(A) \\
    \operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{x \sim \text{uniform}(S_d)} \|A x\|^2 &= \frac{\|\sigma(A)\|^2}{d}
\end{align}
where $\sigma$ yields the singular values of a matrix (note that $\|\sigma(\cdot)\| = \|\cdot\|_\text{F}$ is the Frobenius norm). Is there a similar expression for $\operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{x \sim \text{uniform}(S_d)} \|A x\|$?

Comment: Could you please reference or provide a proof of the case $E_x[\|Ax\|^2]$?

Comment: @Surb Using the trace's linearity and cyclic property, $E\|Ax\|^2 = \text{tr}(A^\top A E[xx^\top])$. Since the squared Frobenius norm is $\text{tr}(A^\top A)$, it remains to show that the covariance matrix of $x$ is $\frac{1}{d} I_d$. I think this can be deduced from rotational invariance and symmetry.

Comment: I don't expect there will be a clean expression for $E \|Ax\|$.

Comment: @Surb https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22764/covariance-matrix-of-uniform-spherical-distribution